# How to handle Antlr whitespace when parsing a string

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

I have a string that I need to parse, that is too heavy for regex. Regex is not too good at finding balanced matches... The task is fairly simple though, as each string can have three types of information:

- Functions
- Variables
- Arbitrary text

I need to interpolate the string so that I can replace the Variables and Functions with content that my program generates, but in place so that the arbitrary text is preserved (incl spaces).

I have found this to be an excellent opportunity to learn ANTLR, but I am struggling getting this to work.

I am basically having problems with three things:

1. I need whitespace to be preserved, as the arbitrary text is not to be lost.
2. I want the args in the function to not care about whitespace
3. I am not sure on how to match the arbitrary text. I have tried a few different options, but none worked for me. Including for instance `.+`, `.+?`, `~[$<]`.

A couple of test strings:

- `"The length of the COMPUTER environment variable is $Length(<Env:COMPUTER>)"`
- `"The last 10 chars of the COMPUTER environment is $Substring($Length(<Env:COMPUTER>)-10, $Length(<Env:COMPUTER>))"`

Here is my code so far:

```
grammar Output;     

start
    :  (expr)* ; 

expr 
    : expr expr 
    | VAR 
    | FUNC '(' commaexpr ')' 
    ; 

commaexpr
    : expr
    | commaexpr ',' commaexpr
    ;


FUNC: '$' ID ; 
VAR : '<' ID '>' ;
fragment ID : [a-zA-Z] | [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9:]+ ; 
WS : [\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

**EDIT:**

I have been able to advance a little bit with this. It seems like I have a solution, kinda. Not sure if my solution is the best choice though:

```
grammar Output;     

start
    :  (expr)* ; 

expr 
    : expr expr 
    | variable
    | function
    | text
    ;

variable
    : VAR
    ;

function
    : FUNC '(' commaexpr ')' 
    ;

commaexpr
    : WS? expr WS?
    | commaexpr ',' commaexpr
    ;

text: TEXT+ ;

FUNC: '$' ID ; 
VAR : '<' ID '>' ;
fragment ID : [a-zA-Z] | [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9:]+ ; 
TEXT: .+?;
NL : [\r\n]+ -> skip ; 
WS: [ ]+ ;
```

Are there any pitfalls to doing it this way? I see that the `text` expression is a list of chars instead of a string, but that works for me, since I can just use GetText() on them in the visitor to get the actual data.

**RESULTS**

I went with a variation of [Bart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837322/95008).

The final code, the ANTLR code as well as the visitorrelevant for this is here: https://github.com/IntelliSearch/FlexVersion/tree/master/IntelliSearch.FlexVersion.OutputParser

And the ovrridden OutputVisitor here: https://github.com/IntelliSearch/FlexVersion/blob/master/IntelliSearch.FlexVersion/OutputVisitor.cs

In case the link dies at one stage, here is the ANTLR g4 file:

```
grammar Output;

start
  : expr* EOF
  ;

expr
 : function
 | variable
 | text
 ;

function
 : FUNC '(' params ')';

variable
 : VAR;

params
 : expr+ ( ',' expr+ )*
 ;

text
 : OTHER+
 ;

FUNC      : '$' ID;
VAR       : '<' ID '>';
OPEN_PAR  : '(';
CLOSE_PAR : ')';
COMMA     : ',';
OTHER     : . ;

fragment ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9:]* ;
```

As you can see I also ditched the operators, (++-/*), as that was only supposed to be allowed in params, but then I wasn't sure if that really would be smart, so instead I went for an approach were that was solved with specific $functions too.

Comment: So spaces that occur inside the function parenthesis should be removed?

Comment: Spaces inside the parenthesis doesn't matter. They can be ignored.

Comment: Note: you don't need to preserve whitespaces in the lexer in order to reproduce the original text. That is still available in the input source and you can use the character indexes from the returned tokens to extract a range of text from the original input, including all whitespaces + comments.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know that. Thanks @MikeLischke

Comment: Is arbitrary text supposed to be allowed inside a function call as well or only outside? That is, should `$f(<x>, lalala)` or `$f(huhu <x> lala)` be allowed? Or for that matter, should `$f(<x> <y>)` (without a comma between the two variables) be allowed?

Comment: @sepp2k I found the same problem myself as you suggested. It started to be complicated, so, I made this easier by "disallowing" this as the spaces change the content. If I wrapped text in quotes this would be clearer, but I wanted the format to be clean. So, I am allowing it and it will be part of the parameter, and if i.e. the param is a string prefixed with a space then the parsed string will start with a space. So, I have suggested for the users to not use spaces, unless they want them to be part of the parsed content. Seems to be an ok tradeoff.

Comment: @Spiralis I didn't quite get whether you'd prefer to disallow it, but decided not to because it'd be too complicated, or whether you don't want to disallow it. If you do want to disallow it, you can just remove `| ignore` from `expr` in Bart's answer (or `| text` in your own attempt - I'm not sure which one you ended up going with) and instead define `start` as `(expr | ignore)* EOF`. Then you can also get rid of `+`s in `params`, to also disallow `$f(<x><y>)` (unless that's supposed to be legal).

Comment: @sepp2k I went more or less with Bart's answer. Meaning that the spaces are allowed, but if added then they will intentionally be a part of the parameter. I also want spaces that the ignore catches in other places (renamed to `text`). In my results all text nodes ended up being only one character, but that was ok. I am using a visitor to get them, and `GetText` passes me the collective result from the node. I do want to allow `$f(<x><y>)`. If `$f( <x><y>)` is used (note the space), then that space is prefixed on the param. I btw also ditched the +-/*, and rather use functions for those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lexer, `.+?` will always consume a single character, so mind as well remove the `+?` part.

I had something like this in mind:

```antlr
grammar Output;

start
  : expr* EOF
  ;

expr
 : FUNC '(' params ')'
 | expr ( MULT | DIV ) expr
 | expr ( PLUS | MINUS ) expr
 | VAR
 | ignore
 ;

params
 : expr+ ( ',' expr+ )*
 ;

ignore
 : OTHER+
 ;

FUNC      : '$' ID;
VAR       : '<' ID '>';
OPEN_PAR  : '(';
CLOSE_PAR : ')';
MULT      : '*';
DIV       : '/';
MINUS     : '-';
PLUS      : '+';
OTHER     : . ;

fragment ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9:]* ;
```

I just saw your own solution, but if that works the way you want it to, that's fine.

Comment: Great. With this solution the function params was flattened too. With mine it formed a deep nested hierarchy, depending on the number of parameters. Thanks :)